# How to filter out some category from AdMob?

Tags: android, ios, admob

My app is a dating app.
I decided to add AdMob to it.

However, too many ads of dating apps show up.

Can I filter out all the kind of the apps?

Comment: Do you mean about the content of your banner inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to restrict certain types of ads from appearing in your app. You can block all app promotion ads, for example, or block categories of things you'd prefer not to present. I'd recommend checking out this Help Center article, which can guide you through the process in the AdMob UI:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6033677